# How to disable set selected of item (gallery) in the middle of the screen when I touch on it in android

Tags: android, android-widget

G'day!

I wanna disable set in the middle of the galler selected item. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great thanks for help!

I've found it myself. If you even need disable auto centered selected item in the middle of the gallery widget, you'll need add next method for gallery:

```
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    setSelection(getSelectedItemPosition());
    return true;
}
```